# C# combobox with search field

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to type values into my combobox and have the combo items filtered where any item does not contain the text I'm typing.

So if I have a combobox with values {"one", "two", "three"}

I could select the combobox and type "o", which would give me "one" and "two" as remaining options.

I can see that this question has been asked before a couple of times, however all the answers are very long and awkward - my favourite example so far being [this.](https://jiangsheng.net/2007/08/06/autocomplete-with-datasource/)

Does anyone know of some more sensible way of accomplishing this?

Comment: there is no out-of-the-box solution for this. The only filter offered by winforms is "begin with", so, for _"o"_ there will be only _"one"_. If you need full text search - it's on you to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking to do this, here is the code I ended up using (vb.net)

```
Private Sub ComboKeyPressed() 'cbRPP = the checkbox. I true cbRPP.Sorted = true so I don't have to manually resort items
    SyncLock "ComboKeyPressed"
        cbRPP.DroppedDown = True
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

        Dim s As String = cbRPP.Text.ToLower()
        Dim toShow As IEnumerable(Of String) = cbRPPItems.Where(Function(x) x.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))

        If Not toShow.Any() Then
            cbRPP.Items.Clear()
        End If

        Dim cbItems = New List(Of String)(cbRPP.Items.OfType(Of String).ToList())

        Dim toRemove = cbItems.Except(toShow).ToList()
        Dim toAdd = toShow.Except(cbItems)

        For Each item In toAdd
            cbRPP.Items.Add(item)
        Next

        For Each item In toRemove
            cbRPP.Items.Remove(item)
        Next
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code:

```
    //Elements of the combobox
    string[] ComboxBoxItems = { "one", "two", "three" };

    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets the items that contains the search string and orders them by its position. Without the union items that don't contain the
        //search string would be permanently removed from the combobox.
        string[] UpdatedComboBoxItems = ComboxBoxItems.Where(x => x.Contains(comboBox1.Text)).OrderBy(x => x.IndexOf(comboBox1.Text)).ToArray();

        //Removes every element from the combobox control. Combobox.Items.Clear causes the cursor position to reset.
        foreach(string Element in ComboxBoxItems)
            comboBox1.Items.Remove(Element);

        //Re-adds all the element in order.
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(UpdatedComboBoxItems);
    }
```

With a test collection {"one", "two", "three"}, these are the outputs in relation to the search string:

- "o": {"one", "two"}
- "e": {"one", "three"}
- "":  {"one", "two", "three"}